# Export fbx with texture but I got this...?

Tags: texturing, .fbx

I tried all the tutorial on the internet, but no working.
I have this simple setup with alpha texture on top of a shader

And it became blank after exporting

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i find that the problem is Blender doesn't support exporting nodes except Principle shader which is very frustrating, if I use one BSDF with tex it is fine, but I'm using alpha texture so it's useless...

Comment: Please read the linked question and it's answer. You will not be able to successfully export a blender material node tree to another program, (maybe with gltf, but very doubtful it will be compatible with other shading networks). You will have to recreate your materials in the destination software in which you import your model to. If this is not your goal, then please clarify what your goal is with an [edit] to your question.

Comment: I believe the link that @Timaroberts provided in the comment answers the question, I'm voting to close this question as it's a duplicate